# document.ready function of jquery not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using phonegap to develop an android application.
So I have developed one page in which I am loading some data in the `document.ready` function of JQuery which is working fine in eclipse browser but i am stuck here when its not working in android emulator.

Is there any other way to do this in android.
Is there a way to debug and check whether that function is called or not or some thing like that?

Can I write in console of DDMS while developing with phonegap as like we do in native application development `system.out.println()`.

Is there any function to achieve this in phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pattern that works for PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile:

In index.html:

```
  <body onload="init();">
```

In a .js file:

```
function init() {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
```

A complete demo is available [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/download/demos-and-tutorials)

console.log should work to show logging in the DDMS view - search in the [PhoneGap google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/phonegap) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$(function() {
    ....
});
```

Also, from what I understand, phonegap loads its' pages via AJAX calls. In which case you may need to bind your specific events using `.live('event', function() { ... })`

Comment: ohk ... actually now i tried a sample code to show a dialog from phonegap' site ... even that code is not working in my emulator.its not showing me any dialog. what can be problem ...? do u know how to right in system console likw system.out.println in phonegap ? ? ?